# Python program will run, but won't be kept open for me to look at the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I am new to Python, and I just started my own programs.

I have some programs that I created using IDLE. These programs will run, but the output is on the screen for about 1/4th of a second before it disappears...

I have searched on the internet but I haven't found a solution... can someone explain why this happens, and how to "counter" it?

Note: I am double-clicking on the file

Thank you!

Examples of code:

```
def loader():
percentage = float(input("what percentage do you want?"))
x = 0
print("\nGoal:{} %".format(percentage))


if percentage <= 100 and percentage > 0:
    while x < percentage:
        x+=1
        print("Loading...{}%".format(x))

else:
    print ("Error, you can't overload/underload")


loader()
```

---

OR

---

```
def trinomial():

a = float(input("a?"))
b = float(input("b?"))
c = float(input("c?"))

print("\n a = {}\n b = {} \n c = {}".format(a,b,c))
print("So you are trying to find x for \n {}x^2 + ({}x) + ({})".format(a,b,c))

delta = b**2 - (4 * a * c)

if delta > 0:
    x1 = (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b + sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    print("For x = {} or x = {}, the trinomial is solved".format(x1, x2))

elif delta < 0:
    print ("No values of x possible")

elif delta == 0: 
    #I know, I could have used "else"
    x1 = -b/(2*a)
    print("For x = {} the trinomial is solved".format(x1)) 

trinomial()
```

Comment: How are you running the program? Through IDLE? Through a terminal? Or by double-clicking on the script?

Comment: @AdamSmith double click

Comment: please share the code of the program

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: The code here is mostly irrelevant, actually. (or perhaps I should say *likely* mostly irrelevant!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave too little information, but probably it is not the problem of Python, but Windows console. Either open your program from the cmd app, or wait until Enter is pressed. Put this at the end of your script.

```
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Comment: `import sys` at the beginning. Sorry, forgot about this

Answer (score 1):

When you double-click on the script, it starts a new instance of `python`, opens a terminal window bound to that instance, runs the script through it (piping output and listening for input on that terminal), then closes the terminal and the instance when the script ends.

The easy way to stop this is to invoke the script from within an existing shell. Run with `python your_script_location`.

Alternatively you can add a request for user input at the end of your code, something like:

```
# after all your other code, just before execution falls off the bottom...
input("Press enter to close...")
```

Comment: @FlipFloop that's more of a user question than a programmer question. Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux? Launch a shell from whichever operating system you're on (Windows is Win+R -> "cmd", Mac I think you have to search for "Terminal" in Spotlight, though there may be some shortcut. Ubuntu, at least, lets you use ctrl+alt+T) then type that in the shell.

Comment: on Windows you should prefer `py -3 your_script_location`. Mac and Linux use `python3 your_script_location`. N.B. that on Mac or Linux, `python scriptname.py` will almost certainly run Python2.